# Validate Form with DataAnnotations and JQuery Ajax submission

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send and validate a form via jquery ajax.
I would like to know if it is possible and how to achieve this.

What do I have?

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
        <section id="result">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        </section>

        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Isbn)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Isbn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Isbn)
        </section>
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookNumber)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BookNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookNumber)
        </section>
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </section>
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </section>

        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    }
```

My javascript:

```
    <script>
            $(function () {
                    $('form').submit(function () {
                            if ($(this).valid()) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                            url: this.action,
                                            type: this.method,
                                            data: $(this).serialize()
                                    })
                                    .success(function (result) {
                                            $('#result').html(result);
                                    })
                                    .error(function () {
                                            alert("oops! some critical stuff");
                                    });
                            }

                            return false;
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

At last, my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Book model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        if (model.Title.IsEmpty())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "What are you doing?? The title can't be emtpy!");
            return View(model);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

So, this is just a case study.
I wanted to have the DataAnnotations working on the client side, which already are. And when I post the form to the server, perform some more validations via ModelState.IsValid and ModelState.AddModelError and have this shown back to the client.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: It is possible. So what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: When I submit the form I end up with two copies of the view.
Possibly because of the target id to be updated.

I would like to know which is the best way to do something like this. Try to stick with the ModelState validations or to return the errors on a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are doing:

1. You submit the form to your controller via Ajax
2. You then return the entire View from the controller (along with any Layouts), and insert it into #result. You now have two copies of the view.

To fix this - make use of a partial view.

i.e. Create a new partial _FormPartial.chstml and place your form contents in it.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <section>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Isbn)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Isbn)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Isbn)
    </section>
    <section>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BookNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookNumber)
    </section>
    <section>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </section>
    <section>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </section>

    <button type="submit">Go</button>
```

Then change your view to use this partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <section id="result">
        @Html.Partial("_FormPartial") 
    </section>       
}
```

And finally, update the return type of your controller to use PartialView instead of View.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Book model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return PartialView("_FormPartial", model);

    if (model.Title.IsEmpty())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "What are you doing?? The title can't be emtpy!");
        return PartialView("_FormPartial", model);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Alternatively, look at using [Ajax.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which does the heavy lifting for you.